# Copying Folders with SHFileOpStruct - Only Newer?

Tags: delphi, copy, directory

Using SHFileOpStruct and the following code I found on the Internet, is there a Flag or Switch to make it only copy newer Files within a Folder? Or, must I check each File within each Folder?

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  OpStruc: TSHFileOpStruct;
  frombuf, tobuf: Array [0..128] of Char;
Begin
  {The fillchars make sure the parameters are terminated by at least
   two #0 characters, this is required since each parameter can hold
   a list of zero-terminated strings, the extra #0 terminates the
   list. }
  fillChar( OpStruc, Sizeof(OpStruc), 0 );
  FillChar( frombuf, Sizeof(frombuf), 0 );
  FillChar( tobuf, Sizeof(tobuf), 0 );
  StrPCopy( frombuf, 'd:\brief\*.*' );
  StrPCopy( tobuf, 'd:\temp\brief' );
  With OpStruc DO Begin
    Wnd:= Handle;
    wFunc:= FO_COPY;
    pFrom:= @frombuf;
    pTo:=@tobuf;
    fFlags:= FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION;
  end;
  ShFileOperation( OpStruc );
end;
Peter Below (TeamB)  100113.1...@compuserve.com)
```

I checked here but could not see anything.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a flag or switch to make it only copy newer files within a folder?

No.

> Must I check each file within each folder?

Yes.